# Get a handle of new window opened

Tags: javascript

I want to insert text in a text box present in new window which is getting open when I am clicking on a link present in parent window

I want to know how I can get a handler of new child window and I can find id of element present in child window and perform action in javascript.

Note-View source of child window and parent is different and on using `document.getElemntByid("")` is not working because- code is not able to find the element because id's of child window is not present in parent window so for that I want handle/switch of child window.

Comment: are you using window.open for opening a new window?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a reference to the window. It could look something like:

```
// reference to child window
var childWin;

function openChildWindow () {
 childWin = window.open('http://...', 'myChildWindow');
}

function childWindowDocument() {
  return 'contentDocument' in childWin ? childWin.contentDocument : childWin.document;
}

// Update a text area inside child window
childWindowDocument().getElementsById('myTextArea').value = 'Updated...';
```